# How do I traverse DOM tree without using element ID's, in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm having trouble traversing the DOM tree without using element ID's.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<dl id="dd-prefix-one" class="dropdown f-left">
  <dt><a href="#">Lorem<span class="value">ipsum</span></a></dt>
  <dd><ul>...</ul></dd>
</dl>
```

Here is the JQuery I'm using at the moment:

```
$('#dd-prefix-one dt a').click(function() { 
    $('#dd-prefix-one dd ul').slideToggle();
    $('#dd-prefix-two dd ul, #dd-prefix-three dd ul, #dd-prefix-four dd ul, #dd-prefix-five dd ul').fadeOut(200); 
});
```

This JQuery is repeated in my code 5 times with just the change in ID's...hence the need to step away from being ID specific.

I have attempted using .prevUntil()...although I must have missed something.

Any help would be Greatly Appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the pasted code:

```
<dl id="dd-prefix-one" class="dropdown f-left">
  <dt><a href="#">Lorem<span class="value">ipsum</span></a></dt>
  <dd><ul>...</ul></dd>
</dl>
```

You could use something like:

```
$('dl dt a').click(
    function() {
        $(this).closest('dl').find('ul').slideToggle();
        $(this).closest('dl').siblings().find('ul').fadeOut(200);
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qQqB8/).

Comment: @Nasir: glad to be of help! =)

Answer (score 2):

Something a bit like this should work (not tested)

```
$('dl.dropdown dt a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('dl').find('ul').slideToggle();
    $('dl.dropdown dt a').not(this).find('ul').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I think I'll be using .find() from now on *****

Answer (score 0):

Abstract it out as a function which takes the id as an argument.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to JavaScript/JQuery. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by Abstracting it into function